# Do any of these sources of AC bonuses conflict or negate each other?

Tags: dnd-5e, armor-class

My understanding, confirmed by the answer to this question:
[When a War Caster Wizard carrying a shield casts the spell "Shield" does the AC bonus Stack?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/50660/when-a-war-caster-wizard-carrying-a-shield-casts-the-spell-shield-does-the-ac) is that anywhere an actual +N bonus to AC is listed, they all stack.

So **does the following work, or is there some conflict between some of these that would not allow them to be used together?**

Barbarian 1 / Cleric 1 / Wizard 5

Unarmored, with a shield. Con 18, Dex 15

- Base AC is 10 + 2 (dex) + 4 (con) = 16
- Shield (+2 AC) raises this to 18

Casts Haste as an action and Shield of Faith as a Bonus Action (a house rule allows 2 concentration spells):

- Haste gives +2 AC, for AC 20
- Shield of Faith gives +2 AC, bringing AC up to 22

If she ever gets hit, cast Shield as a reaction:

- an additional +5 to AC bringing AC up to 27 for one round

I know all of these would stack, but does anything prevent them from all being used together?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are almost exactly correct.

All the math you have is accurate. However, you've missed a subtle rule mentioned in the PHB (pg. 202) regarding spells cast as Bonus Actions. Namely, when casting a spell as a bonus action

> You can't cast another spell during the same turn, except for a cantrip with a casting time of 1 action.

Thus, while it is possible to reach 27 AC using the methods you've described, you cannot cast Haste and Shield of Faith on a single turn.